# In which case System.UnicodeString.Format is used?

Tags: c++builder

My environment is RADStudio XE4 Update1 on Windows 7 pro (32bit).

I found that in C++ Builder there is a [`System::UnicodeString::Format()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.UnicodeString.Format) static method.

`Format()` can be used as follows. However, the same thing can be carried out by using `String().sprintf()`, I think.

```
String str;

// --- (1) ---
str = String::Format(L"%2d, %2d, %2d", ARRAYOFCONST((10, 2, 3)));
ShowMessage(str); // 10, 2, 3

// --- (2) ---
str = String().sprintf(L"%2d, %2d, %2d", 10, 2, 3);
ShowMessage(str); // 10, 2, 3
```

My question is in which case the `Format()` is used better than by using other functions?

Is this just a matter of taste?

Comment: Thank you for editing for better reading the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, `UnicodeString::Format()` calls [`Sysutils::Format()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SysUtils.Format), which is Delphi's formatting function.  Remember that the majority of the RTL/VCL/FMX is written in Delphi, not C++.

Internally, `UnicodeString::sprint()` calls the C runtime's `vsnwprintf()` function instead.

Different frameworks, different interfaces, different formatting rules, similar results.

One benefit of using `UnicodeString::Format()` instead of `UnicodeString::sprint()` is that `Format()` performs type checking at runtime.  If it detects a mismatch while comparing the formatting string to the input parameters, it will raise an exception.  `UnicodeString::sprintf()` does not do that, it interprets the input values exactly as you specify in the formatting string, so if you get something wrong then you risk corrupting the output or outright crashing your code.

But, if you are careful with your parameters, the differences come down to a matter of taste.
.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. So, Format() is based on Delphi's function. And Format() is type-safe. That's what I would like to know. I appreciate it.